# How to send error notification instead of next notification in an observable stream?

Tags: angular, rest, error-handling, rxjs

I have an API which responds an object like this:

```
{
       "statusCode": 200,
       "errors": [],
       "data": []
}
```

Sometimes it responds with data and sometimes responds with an array of errors.
but the status code in headers always is 200 (OK).
so the subscriber always gets next notification in observable stream even if the respond has some errors.
the question is how can I transform the next notification to error notification in observable stream so the subscriber get error notification like when the request is not (OK).
I can't use `throw new Error()`  because it only can accept string while I want to give subscriber response object.

Comment: You should talk to your backend devs. Returning `HTTP 200` when an error occurred is not correct.

Comment: Is it a `GraphQL` API ? you should use Apollo Client for angular if it's `GraphQL`, it will handle this by default and in the subscribe  you can use `next` and `error` for error handling

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to build an interceptor to do it. Something like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ErrorResponseInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      map((response) => {
        if (!(response instanceof HttpResponse)) {
          return response;
        }
        if (
          !Object.keys(response.body).includes('errors') ||
          response.body.errors.length == 0
        ) {
          return response;
        }

        return new HttpResponse({
          body: response.body.errors,
          status: 500,
          statusText: 'Internal server error',
          url: response.url ?? undefined,
        });
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Then register this interceptor in your `app.module`:

```js
providers: [
  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: ErrorResponseInterceptor,
    multi: true,
  },
],
```